# unable to unpack libgdal

Tags: apt

I am trying to install opengeo-suite and it seems due to some reason I am unable to install due to the libgdal unable to be unpacked.

This is the error I get everytime i execute `apt-get install opengeo-suite`

```
Unpacking libgdal (from .../libgdal_1.8.1-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libgdal_1.8.1-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/gdal-config', which is also in package libgdal-dev 1.9.0-1~exp5p1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

......

```
Unpacking opengeo-suite (from .../opengeo-suite_2.5_amd64.deb) ...
    Processing triggers for man-db ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/libgdal_1.8.1-1_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libgdal_1.8.1-1_amd64.deb
apt-get -f install
```

Comment: @Sam007 Glad that it helped :)

Comment: Does your command mean I will overwrite a newer version of *libgdal*? This is the output of the first command: `trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/gdal...', which is also in package gdal-bin 1.9.1-2~precise3`. If I have a newer version of *libgdal* installed how would I keep this as a parallel installation?

Comment: @JJD - Maybe it's better to submit it as a separate question?